# iOS phone gap - push notification does not display notification service alert box

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I've been tried to apply iOS push notification through tutorial here - 
 http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/

As tutorial instruction indicated, I implemented push notification folder to xcode plugins folder then, I added below code to AppDelegate.m class

```
#import "PushNotification.h"
    /* START BLOCK */
#pragma PushNotification delegation

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
   [pushHandler didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)appdidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:  
   (NSError*)error{
      PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
      [pushHandler didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary*)userInfo
 {
    PushNotification* pushHandler = [self.viewController   getCommandInstance:@"PushNotification"];
NSMutableDictionary* mutableUserInfo = [userInfo mutableCopy];

// Get application state for iOS4.x+ devices, otherwise assume active
UIApplicationState appState = UIApplicationStateActive;
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(applicationState)]) {
    appState = application.applicationState;
}

[mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationLaunchNotification"];
if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"1" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
    [pushHandler didReceiveRemoteNotification:mutableUserInfo];
} else {
    [mutableUserInfo setValue:@"0" forKey:@"applicationStateActive"];
    [mutableUserInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:@"timestamp"];
    [pushHandler.pendingNotifications addObject:mutableUserInfo];
}
}
/* STOP BLOCK */
```

and added below javascript code to index.js

```
// license to apache software .....
var app = {
    myLog: document.getElementById("log"),
    initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
bindEvents: function() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener('resume', this.onResume, false);
},
onResume: function() {
    app.myLog.value="";
// Clear the badge number - if a new notification is received it will have a number set on it for the badge
app.setBadge(0);
app.getPending(); // Get pending since we were reopened and may have been launched from a push notification
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.register(); // Call to register device immediately every time since unique token can change (per Apple)

// This will cause to fire when app is active already
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                          console.log('RECEIVED NOTIFICATION! Push-notification! ' + event);
                          app.myLog.value+=JSON.stringify(['\nPush notification received!', event]);
                          // Could pop an alert here if app is open and you still wanted to see your alert
                          //navigator.notification.alert("Received notification - fired Push Event " + JSON.stringify(['push-//notification!', event]));
                          });
document.removeEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);
},
setBadge: function(num) {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
app.myLog.value+="Clear badge... \n";
pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(num);
},
receiveStatus: function() {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.getRemoteNotificationStatus(function(status) {
                                             app.myLog.value+=JSON.stringify(['Registration check - getRemoteNotificationStatus', status])+"\n";
                                             }); 
},
getPending: function() {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.getPendingNotifications(function(notifications) {
                                         app.myLog.value+=JSON.stringify(['getPendingNotifications', notifications])+"\n";
                                         console.log(JSON.stringify(['getPendingNotifications', notifications]));
                                         });
},
register: function() {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.registerDevice({alert:true, badge:true, sound:true}, function(status) {
                                app.myLog.value+=JSON.stringify(['registerDevice status: ', status])+"\n";
                                app.storeToken(status.deviceToken);
                                });
},
storeToken: function(token) {
console.log("Token is " + token);
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:8888",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("token="+token+"&message=pushnotificationtester");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        //a response now exists in the responseTest property.
        console.log("Registration response: " + xmlhttp.responseText);
        app.myLog.value+="Registration server returned: " + xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
}    
};
```

it seems like pushNotification.registerDevice function returns null status. 
and i am still not sure why notification authentic alert ('application' would like to send you push notification) is not displayed on iOS device. 
am I missing something? what makes registerDeivce function returns null value??
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you register with Apple to obtain push notificaton token etc?

Answer (score 7):

If register fails means check the app id is enabled and configured the production or development push notification. If not enable it and check or reconfigure it and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not app.myLog that is null? Maybe because you didn't copy the index.html and has no 'log' element in your html?